# CountryData and the areas of the world

Tags: curated-data, geography

If I add the water area and the land area of the world, I get the same number as if I asked for the total area of the world in the first place:

```
In[1]:= {CountryData["World", "WaterArea"] + CountryData["World", "LandArea"],
         CountryData["World", "Area"]}

Out[1]= {5.10066*10^8, 5.10066*10^8}
```

Now, if I add the area of all the countries, it does not add up to the total land area of the world:

```
In[2]:= {Total[CountryData[#, "Area"] & /@ CountryData[]], 
         CountryData["World", "LandArea"]}

Out[2]= {1.35936*10^8, 1.4912*10^8}
```

So my question is: are some countries missing? Are the ice caps to blame?

Comment: "Are the ice caps to blame?" - in a sense, yes; note that Antarctica is not in the list returned by `CountryData[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Curiously `CountryData["World", "LandArea"] - CountryData["Antarctica", "Area"] <
  Total[CountryData[#, "Area"] & /@ CountryData[]]`

Comment: Antarctica is not a sovereign country, but it is part of the world

Comment: @belisarius: compare as well the output of `Total[Flatten[CountryData[#, "Area"] & /@ CountryData["Continents"]]]` with `CountryData["World", "LandArea"]`. Curious indeed.

Comment: @J.M. Try `Complement[Flatten[CountryData[#] & /@ CountryData["Continents"]], 
 CountryData[]]`

Comment: @belisarius, it returns what I expect. My point was that totaling all the areas of those gives a result somewhat different from `CountryData["World", "LandArea"]`...

Comment: @J.M. Well, something the size of New Zealand is lost

Comment: @belisarius Your rugby team has destroyed it  :-(

Comment: @wxffles No, we are still around and listed in `CountryData`. We are not part of Australia yet. :-)

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179031/itsy-bitsy-teeny-weeny-little-polka-dot-island-in-countrydata has some other peculiarities in Mathematica's view of what constitutes the world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So both

```
CountryData["World", "LandArea"] - 
(CountryData["Antarctica", "LandArea"] +
 Total[CountryData[#, "LandArea"] & /@ CountryData[]])
```

and

```
CountryData["World", "LandArea"] - 
  Total[Flatten[CountryData[#, "LandArea"] & /@ CountryData["Continents"]]]
```

give $3.42636\times10^6 \text{ km}^2$ of area missing. That is approximately the area of current Arctic ice ([I Googled it](http://www.firstpost.com/world/arctic-sea-ice-melts-to-lowest-level-on-record-461625.html)).

Also, there are some places that occupy a land area, but are not within any country (about maybe $10^4 \text{ km}^2$ in total); e.g., the Saudi–Iraqi neutral zone.

Comment: Great! Let's reevaluate those commands in a year to see if they change.