# Area of countries given by GeoBoundaries does not equal area in database

Tags: curated-data, geodesy

```
In[3]:= GeoArea[CountryData["World", "FullPolygon"]]/CountryData["World", "LandArea"]                                                                           

Out[3]= 0.918839
```

Why don't the polygons of the World add up to the world's land area? I've read [CountryData and the areas of the world](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10229/countrydata-and-the-areas-of-the-world) but think this is a different issue, since Antarctica is part of the world.

I realize `GeoArea[CountryData["World", "FullPolygon"]]` doesn't include the part of Antarctica south of 89.9 degrees, but this isn't enough to compensate for the difference.

Comment: I suspect it is because Polygons are just an approximation to the full geo boundary.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork this makes it difficult to do geographical analysis. I assumed Mathematica's curated data, especially using FullPolygon, would be complete. Are you saying there are more complete sources?

Comment: No FullPolygon will go down to 1 cm of coastline (for instance)... every polygon is an *approximation*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork How did you know it was 1cm? :) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/179031/itsy-bitsy-teeny-weeny-little-polka-dot-island-in-countrydata

Comment: Of COURSE I don't know that it is 1 cm.  Of COURSE.  That's why I wrote "(for instance)."  But think about the *principle* here.  Do you understand the issue at hand?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I was joking -- note the smiley face and the linked question.

Comment: Actually CountryData["World", "FullPolygon"] does not contain Antarctica. That accounts for the missing 8%. Check with GeoArea[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Antarctica"]] / CountryData["World", "LandArea"].

Comment: @jose You are correct and I actually ran into this earlier at https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/STACK/bc-equ-dist.m and forgot. The only part I remembered was that Antarctica's polygons stop at 89.9 degrees south. If you make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks. Answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antarctica is not included in `CountryData["World", "FullPolygon"]`. Its area explains the missing 8%:

```
GeoArea[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Antarctica"]] / CountryData["World", "LandArea"]
(* 0.0838191 *)
```

You can obtain a polygon that contains Antarctica using the entity

```
world = Entity["GeographicRegion", "World"];
```

Then we have

```
GeoArea[world] / world["LandArea"]
(* 0.98607 *)
```

and now the 1.4% missing can be attributed to imperfections of the polygons.